# Certification passing score on Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013?

Tags: 2013, certification, 70-331

Browsing the official [Exam 70-331 Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-331.aspx) certification page and its [Wiki](http://borntolearn.mslearn.net/certification/server/w/wiki/506.331-core-solutions-of-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx#fbid=MV2e3Sn0PAY) along with using a popular [search engine](https://www.google.se/search?q=google&oq=google&aqs=chrome..69i57l2j69i65j69i60j69i65j69i60.1060j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=Certification%20score%20%22Exam%2070-331%22) I'm unable to find passing score.

Reading blogs all around I find three different figures: [700](http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/studying-for-exam-70-331-core-solutions-of-microsoft-sharepoint-2013/), 750 and 800 of a 1000 possible. But I'm not sure which source to trust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal passing level is 700 for all Microsoft certifications. But on some exams this exact figure can not be reached, so the limit becomes a bit higher.

1000 is the maximum exam score

From the [FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/certification-exam-policies.aspx#exam_basics):

> Additionally, a common misperception is that you must answer 70 percent of the questions correctly in order to pass the exam because the passing score is 700; however, this is a scaled score. The actual percentage of questions that you must answer correctly varies from exam to exam and may be more or less than 70 percent, depending on the input provided by the subject-matter experts who helped us set the cut score and the difficulty of the questions delivered when you take exam.

Comment: I'm too a bit confused about the writings about this specific test, since they do not mention an exact passing score, but in their exam guidelines they say it is (for all certs) "700 or in some cases higher" and that they can change the bar without further notice. So better not to stare blind at the numbers I guess ;)

Comment: Added some more details and a source. Though from my phone, so a bit help with the mark up would be great :)